# For loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code:

```
newsArray = ["John"," Lisa"," Carl"];
```

And this code in a button event click:

```
for (var i = 0; i <newsArray.length; i++){

 alert("Name: " + newsArray[i]);
}
```

The code now output "Name: John" "Name: Lisa" "Name: Carl"

Is it possible that second time i click the button, it will only show "Lisa" and "Carl" ?

Comment: Of course. What problem did you encounter while trying to implement what you describe?

Answer (score 6):

You need to expand the code to set a variable that indicates this is second request.

Expand your code to the following.

```
var start = 0;
for (var i = start; i <newsArray.length; i++){
  alert("Name: " + newsArray[i]);
}
if (start == 0) start++; // increment start if this is the first time
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the first element of an array with the shift() method.  This is destructive, but would do the job:

```
function clickHandler() {
  newsArray.forEach(function (name) { console.log(name); });
  newsArray.shift();
}
```

Comment: Just a note. `Array.forEach()` will not work for IE earlier than IE9

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to keep array values, you can use array `shift` method.

```
newsArray = ["John"," Lisa"," Carl"];

for (var i = 0; i <newsArray.length; i++){
 alert("Name: " + newsArray[i]);
}

newsArray.shift();
```

Hope it helps.